# Is there a way to add ROW_NUMBER() without using OVER (ORDER BY ...) in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-order-by

Is there a way to add `ROW_NUMBER()` simply based on the default row order without using `OVER (ORDER BY ...)`?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.  Perhaps with sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag, it would.  I would caution though that questions of the sort:  "Is there another way to do something when there is a built-in function?" are not usually high quality.

Comment: SQL Datasets don't have an implicit ordering, they're explicitly unordered.  For `ROW_NUMBER()` to do anything useful you have to tell it how to calculate the order of your set from the data itself; thus, the `ORDER BY` clause.  So, this begs the question; WHY do you want to do this?

Comment: question would be why?. what is your goal of doing this

Comment: which dbms are you using?

Comment: Thanks. I have already ordered the dataset in the desired way after some manipulation. There is an alternative way of using ORDER BY... Just wondering if it is feasible to just add the row number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no implicit ordering to rows in a table, it is a logical unordered set.

however you can do  `row_number() over (order by (select null))`

As suggested by Itzik Ben-Gan from his book on `window functions`.

Answer (score 1):

For PostgreSQL and MYSQL 8.0

```
row_number()over()
```

For SQL Server and oracle it will be:

```
row_number()over(order by (select null))
```

But this without mentioning proper order by clause it's not guaranteed to have same row number for a column everytime.

Comment: Oracle supports an empty `over()` as well